# Употребление корней "кас" и "кос"

Tags: орфография

В каких случаях пишется корень "-кас-", а в каких "-кос-"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если после корня есть суффикс "-а-", то пишется "-к**а**с-", если же суффикса нет, а идет сочетание букв "-сн-", то пишется "-к**о**с-".
Примеры: *прик**а**саться, прик**о**снуться, к**а**сательная, прик**о**сновение*.

Answer (score 0):

Следует правописание данного корня с чередованием о//а отличать от корня с безударной гласной кОса, кОсить.